# Version-dependent type inheritance in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does the following code work only under Node.js 5.x and 6.x, but breaks in 4.x and earlier versions?

Is there a way to modify it in such a way to make work in any Node.js 0.10.x - 6.x?

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');

function Parent() {
}

Parent.prototype.show = function () {
    return this.msg(); // virtual-like call;
};

function Child() {
}

Child.prototype.msg = function () {
    return 'Hello!';
};

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

var test = new Child();

console.log(test.show());
```

In Node.js 5.x and 6.x it displays `Hello!`. And in any earlier version of Node.js it displays `TypeError: this.msg is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the two different versions of code I found that the only difference between them is the way in which prototypical inheritance is achieved.

[**4.x**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.x/lib/util.js#L745)

```
ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
});
```

Where `ctor` is the child constructor and `superCtor` is the parent constructor.

[**Master**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L828)

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(ctor.prototype, superCtor.prototype);
```

Where `ctor` is the child constructor and `superCtor` is the parent constructor.

---

For versions 4.x (and below probably), the parent's prototype is assigned to the child's prototype, thus, *completely replacing it*.

However, the latest version uses [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) which **I'm assuming** doesn't replace the child's prototype but preserves both the child's prototype as well as parent's prototype.

Update: I found [this](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.setprototypeof) in the ECMAScript 2017 spec, if it's of any help...

Comment: Unfortunately, `setPrototypeOf` doesn't exist in Node.js 0.10.x. Any idea how to work-around this?

Comment: You can use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#Polyfill) for `Object.setPrototypeOf` or make your own custom `inherits` function.

Comment: Using the polyfill for `setPrototypeOf` is the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Node 5.0, `util.inherits` used `Object.create()` to create the inheritance chain. This unfortunately had a bug. Anything you attached to `Child.prototype` *prior* to using `util.inherits` was removed—which is what is causing your bug. As of 5.0 and later, Node uses `Object.setPrototypeOf` under the hood.

Luckily, the fix is super simple. Move the `util.inherits` call *before* you add methods to `Child.prototype`.

The following code will work from 0.10 to 6.0.

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');

function Parent() {
}

Parent.prototype.show = function () {
  return this.msg(); // virtual-like call;
};

function Child() {
}

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

Child.prototype.msg = function () {
  return 'Hello!';
};

var test = new Child();

console.log(test.show());
```

Comment: Great answer, right to the point! That little trick did it! :)

Comment: After trying to use it I found it not usable across several modules. It can only work within just one JavaScript file, which is hardly usable. I found it that using the polyfill for `setPrototypeOf` (earlier answer by @Blaze) is a far better solution.

Comment: Can you give me an example where it's not usable?

Comment: I have classes Parent, ChildA, ChildB - all sitting in separate modules. The only way to correct the sequence of prototyping is by moving them all into a single module. It is not possible otherwise. I would have to have them all declared first, then do the inheritance, and only then add all the prototype methods. Such mess requires that it is all in one file.

Comment: Not necessarily! All that has to happens is that your `util.inherits()` calls need to be before you add anything to the prototype.

Comment: In my library the `Parent` is inside `index.js`, loads all the children, initiates inheritance for them and then exposes those types via `module.exports`. This cannot work, because children have all `prototype` implementations inside the corresponding modules, which needs to be loaded within `index.js`, which means inheritance can only happen after loading children, which then would lose their `prototype` methods.